# Tem problema criar um elemento e definir o id como vazio?

Tags: php, html

Eu pretendo criar uma função php que crie elementos html de forma mais ágil, a sintaxe devera ser mais ou menos como uma extensão do sublime faz:

```
create("p#paragrafo.classe1.classe2.classe3=content");
a saida devera ser: <p id="paragrafo" class="classe1 classe2 classe3">content</p>
```

Só que dai se eu passar assim `p#.classe1=content` ele vai criar `<p id="" class="classe1">content</p>`. Tem problema ficar aquele `id=""`?

**A funcao finalizada:**

```
function create ($str) {
    $text = substr($str, strpos($str, "=") + 1);
    $close = "";
    $str = str_replace("=$text", "", $str);
    for ($i = 0, $j = substr_count($str, ">") + 1; $i < $j; $i++) {
        # substring
        $substr = ($pos = strpos($str, ">"))?substr($str, 0, $pos):$str;
        # posicao id
        $posId = strpos($substr, "#");
        # posicao class
        $posClass = strpos($substr, ".");
        # tag
        $tag = substr($substr, 0, $posId);
        # id
        $id = substr($substr, $posId + 1, $posClass - $posId - 1);
        # class
        $class = str_replace(".", " ", substr($substr, $posClass + 1));
        # nao sei o que comentar
        $close = "/$tag$close";
        $str = str_replace("$substr>", "", $str);
        # saida
        echo "$tag class='$class' id='$id'";
        echo "<br><br>";
    }
    # saida
    echo $text;
    echo "<br><br>";
    echo $close;
}
```

Comment: A sua pergunta é: Todos os elementos HTML devem conter um ID?

Comment: nao e so se eu posso definir o id mas nao escrever nada entre as aspas, id="", tem algum problema?

Comment: Problema, não, só é desnecessário e não faz muito sentido fazê-lo. Ao especificar `p#paragrafo` não deveria ser gerado `<p id="paragrafo">`? E por quê não especificar `p.classe1` apenas, se o `id` não é necessário?

Comment: [Is an ID allowed to be empty in an HTML tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6535934/is-an-id-allowed-to-be-empty-in-an-html-tag)

Comment: id="" e o mesmo que nao definir um id ou vai identificar como se tivesse um id com um nome invalido?

Comment: Tente validar aqui https://validator.w3.org

Comment: Você pode preferencialmente detectar elementos vazios e remove-los ou então nem adiciona-los.

Comment: algum problema grave na funcao? Ou sera que ja da pra usar?

Answer (score 0):

Conforme a [W3](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-id) (tradução minha):

> Tokens ID e NOME devem começar com uma letra([A-Za-z]) e podem ser
>   seguidos por qualquer número de letras, dígitos([0-9]), hiphens("-"),
>   underscores("_"), dois pontos(":") e pontos finais(".").

Segundo essa definição id's vazios não são válidos. Embora nada te impeça de usar eles não é possível garantir como os browsers irão os iterpretar.

Answer (score 0):

Problema não tem, caso vc não for precisar fazer referência ao ID do elemento no seu projeto.

> Em relação à resposta do amigo @Genos, embora tenha citado a fonte do
>   [W3](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-id), o ID e NAME **não necessariamente** precisam começar com letra.